# Accesing LAMPP mysql via the command line on linux

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, lampp

I've have installed LAMPP, I need to access MySQL from the terminal but I dont know how, because if I simply type `mysql` into the prompt it says the mysql program is not installed, but it has to be installed because it stands for Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP + Perl. Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system this solved my problem

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u username
```

Answer (score 6):

**My solution:**

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status

cd /opt/lampp/bin

./mysql -h localhost test
```

Answer (score 1):

For [Bitnami LAMP](https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp) stack

```
/opt/lampstack-7.1.23-0/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be to run `which mysql` to locate the binary and check if it is actually installed. If it is missing try re-installing.